# Polymorphism and pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, polymorphism

So based on the comments below, I want to confirm this code is illegal for reasons including:

1. We've created an object joe from an abstract class Employee
2. Since printCheck() was not defined, it makes HourlyEmployee an abstract class like Employee. Thus, we've made object joe from an abstract class.

?

```
class Employee
{
public:
  Employee();
  Employee(const string& theName, const string& theSsn);
  string getName() const;
  string getSsn() const;
  double getNetPay() const;
  void setName(const string& newName);
  void setSsn(const string& newSsn);
  void setNetPay(double newNetPay);
  virtual void printCheck() const = 0;
private:
  string name;
  string ssn;
  double netPay;
};


class HourlyEmployee : public Employee
{
public: 
  HourlyEmployee(); 
  //<Some more legal member function definitions, none of which are 
  //pure virtual functions.> 
private: 
  double wageRate;
  double hours;
};


int main( )
{
  Employee joe; 
  joe = HourlyEmployee();
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't legal and it won't compile.

Comment: @jyim Care to elaborate why you think it's legal?

Comment: And before you post next question "Why Joe is not polymorphic", you are doing an object slicing here as well

Comment: According to the textbook answer, it says it's legal, but I thought otherwise...so it's definitely illegal for the reasons originally stated?

Comment: @jyim, throw your text book into the nearest bin. Or better still burn it.

Comment: @aleguna lol, it's apparently a famous/popular textbook: Absolute C++ by Savitch

Comment: @jyim, then you skipped crucial parts of the example and typed contensts `main` function incorrectly

Comment: nope, this is copy + paste! perhaps there was a typo in the electronic version

Comment: Looks similar to python syntax. C++ uses pointers and references for the base class. 

HourlyEmployee will be abstract unless it overrides (i.e. implements) printCheck()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is illegal is:

Employee is an abstract base class. This line:

```
Employee joe;
```

is illegal on its own, it is creating an instance of your abstract class.

```
joe = HourlyEmployee();
```

is a bad idea even if the classes were both complete as it would slice. joe is an object, not a reference.

If HourlyEmployee remains abstract (does not implement printCheck()) then of course your line is illegal because you are creating a (temporary) instance of one.

Incidentally if both classes were complete, thus the code compiled, but printCheck() remained virtual (not pure), then

```
joe.printCheck();
```

would invoke the Employee version not the HourlyEmployee version because joe is of type Employee and remains so in spite of the assignment. That is why slicing is mostly a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

HourlyEmployee class needs to implements printCheck() function of the base class.
Once you implement this function, HourlyEmployee is a objectable class.